# Could not deduce type of unused parameter - disappears if parameter is used

Tags: haskell, ghc

I have a program that given a set of recipes and a desired output will tell me how many of the intermediate products I will need to make.

```
data Recipe = Recipe { name :: String
                     , ingredients :: [(Recipe, Int)]
                     } deriving (Eq)

instance Show Recipe where
        show Recipe{name=n} = show n

foldRecipes :: (Integral a) => [(Recipe, a)] -> (Recipe, a) -> [(Recipe, a)] 
foldRecipes acc r@(Recipe{ingredients=i}, n) = 
         acc ++ requirements [(recipe, fromIntegral count * n) | (recipe, count) <- i]

requirements :: (Integral a) => [(Recipe, a)] -> [(Recipe, a)] 
requirements m = 
        foldl foldRecipes m m

main = 
        let dough = Recipe{ name = "dough", ingredients = [(flour, 200), (water, 200)] }
            flour = Recipe{ name = "flour", ingredients = [] }
            water = Recipe{ name = "water", ingredients = [] }

        in putStrLn $ show $ requirements [(dough, 2)]
```

Outputs: `[("dough",2),("flour",400),("water",400)`

On my way to making this, I ran into the fact that the following version does not work, could somebody explain why? If I use an explicit `Int` instead of `Integral a` for the type signatures it does work.

```
foldRecipes :: (Integral a) => [(Recipe, a)] -> (Recipe, a) -> [(Recipe, a)]
foldRecipes acc r@(Recipe{ingredients=i}, _) =
         acc ++ requirements i
```

Output:

```
test_unused.hs:10:30:
    Could not deduce (a ~ Int)
    from the context (Integral a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 foldRecipes :: Integral a =>
                                [(Recipe, a)] -> (Recipe, a) -> [(Recipe, a)]
      at test_unused.hs:8:16-76
      `a' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the type signature for
            foldRecipes :: Integral a =>
                           [(Recipe, a)] -> (Recipe, a) -> [(Recipe, a)]
          at test_unused.hs:8:16
    Expected type: [(Recipe, a)]
      Actual type: [(Recipe, Int)]
    In the first argument of `requirements', namely `i'
    In the second argument of `(++)', namely `requirements i'
    In the expression: acc ++ requirements i
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foldRecipes :: (Integral a) => [(Recipe, a)] -> (Recipe, a) -> [(Recipe, a)]
foldRecipes acc r@(Recipe{ingredients=i}, _) =
     acc ++ requirements i
```

The above does not work because `ingredients` always contains a list of type `[(Recipe, Int)]` whereas your function accepts lists that use a generic integral type `Integral a`. `a` and `Int` are different types and you cannot concatenate lists of different types using `++`.

Your other version of the function works because there you use `fromIntegral` to convert from `Int` to the more generic type.